# What program can I use to invert the state of Shift?

Tags: scripting, x11, keyboard

I want the Shift key to behave as if it was inverted, when it is not being pressed, it's state should be set to 'pressed' and when it is being held down, then it's state should be 'released'.
This should function globally and affect all programs.

This would effectively enable typing in caps and all special characters, while NOT holding Shift down in a text editor, for instance.

What software can I use and how would I use it to do so? If there is such a software.

To clarify, what I need is a way to invert the internal state of the Shift key, when I press Shift, the internal state would be set to 'released', and when I release Shift, the internal state is set to 'pressed'. I can't think of another way to explain it, seems pretty straight forward. Simply inverting the Shift key, I can think of a way to do it by modifying my keyboard, but I don't want to do that.

I'm running Peppermint OS (based on debian 11)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will need to state your operating system. Also your tags are not coherent. This question has nothing to do with bash.

Comment: By the way, isn't that exactly what hitting the caps lock key does for you?

Comment: Hitting the Caps Lock button does not invert the internal state of Shift, it simply toggles the internal state of Caps Lock.

Comment: But that internal state you speak of doesn't *really* exist, from a keyboard's point of view. The keyboard just sends "shift key has begun to be pressed", "shift key has been held for a while now" and "shift key has been released" **events**. How these events are tracked, and what that means for characters that get inserted into e.g. a text field, that's up to the program you're interacting with. So you'd need to patch every program that receives key press events.

Comment: Well, then I need a software that intercepts the events and sends the inverted event in it's place, when a "shift key has begun to be pressed" event occurs, the software would send a "shift key has been released" event instead, and vice-versa.

Comment: But that's logically impossible, because your keyboard isn't sending "has been released" events all the time.

Comment: Serious question: this sounds like assistive technology. Maybe there is another way to achieve what you need. I just don't think "a software that inverts the shift key" is going to take you there. Maybe tell us about *why* you need that functionality? We're here to help!

Comment: Well, I tried several different keyboard remapping tools, the closest I got to this was using AutoKey, it has a method to send keyboard signals, I managed to bind the shift release event to the shift key being pressed, and it works, but there is no way to monitor for key release events in order to fire the key press in it's place.

Other tools do have a monitoring feature like xmodmap but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: We get that, but the problem is, what you want to do won't work (see my comments above for the technical reasons it won't work). So, **why** do you want to do this thing which seems not possible? Maybe there's another way to achieve that which you actually want this **for**!

Comment: I see, well, I want this because I don't want to keep holding Shift for certain actions, and to avoid stretching my hand several times and while holding Shift.
I guess what I would like is something similar to Sticky Keys, but that is permanent, like Shift Lock, but then, I need to temporarily disable it sometimes by holding down another modifier, or Shift itself.